# AML issue with anaconda

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

After I upgraded AML SDK within conda virtual environment I have started getting error in my MacOS as follows:

print(azureml.core.**version**)
1.0.76

from azureml.train.automl import AutoMLConfig

ImportError: cannot import name 'AutoMLConfig'

Answer (score 0):

Could you please follow the below steps.
 -

1. Completely uninstall conda and reinstall.
2. Build the azure_automl env using [automl_setup_mac](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/automated-machine-learning/automl_setup_mac.sh).
3. run **from azureml.train.automl import AutoMLConfig** to work.

Please follow the below document for automl setup using local conda environment.
https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/tree/master/how-to-use-azureml/automated-machine-learning#localconda